# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net

Estoy intentando lanzar un comando desde esta clase:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class GestionSql
    Private sReturn As String = ""
    Private sConection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" +Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\TPV.mdb;"
    Private oConection As OleDb Connection
    Public oCommand As New OleDbCommand

    Public Function Launch(ByVal value As String) As String
        Try
            oConection.Open()
            oConection = New OleDbConnection(sConection)
            oCommand.CommandText = Value
            sReturn = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            oConection.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("La contraseña es: " + sReturn.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return sReturn
    End Function
End Class
```

En esta clase:

```
Public Class IDVendedor
    Private GestionSql As New GestionSql
    Private sCmd As String
    Private sPass As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Montamos y lanzamos el comando
        sCmd = "SELECT Password FROM Vendedores WHERE Id=" + id.Text
        sPass = GestionSql.Launch(sCmd)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Me salta el error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Me señala que el error está en ExecuteNonQuery en el parámetro sCmd.

Comment: Deberías añadir una pequeña descripción de qué es lo que estás intentando hacer con esas clases (para dar algo más de contexto a los usuarios).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error `Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto` te acompañará durante muchos años en el mundo de la programación, pero dentro de poco te acostumbrarás a saber de inmediato donde esta el error :)

### ¿Qué significa ese mensaje?

Estás leyendo una propiedad o ejecutando una función de una variable de objeto ("referencia de objeto") que no ha sido inicializada ("no establecida como instancia de un objeto"). Esto es, declaraste una variable y la usaste sin asignarle antes un valor.

El error te aparece en la línea 15 de tu captura, porque tienes invertida la inicialización de la variable `oConexion` (línea 16) y el primer uso (línea 15):

```
oConection.open()
oConection = New OleDbConnection(sConection)
```

Para solucionar solo tienes que inicializar la variable `oConexion` antes de abrir la conexión:

```
oConection = New OleDbConnection(sConection) 
oConection.open()
```

Comment: Yo creo que el error es del parámetro que le paso a la función...

me da este error en el orden que tu dices @Roimer:

https://gyazo.com/605021aa3f60d3ac2669f194e83b9571

Y como lo tenía yo antes da este error: https://gyazo.com/b888c68ad88b6a9585df8d7f6baff597

Comment: OK, no había visto el código completo. El otro problema es que el objeto `oCommand` fue creado, le asignaste la consulta, y lo ejecutaste, pero en ningún lado le indicaste que usara la conexión `oConenction`. Creo que lo puedes asignar así: 
`oCommand.conection = oConenction`  antes de llamar a `oCommand.executenonQuery()` (no tengo VS a mano para probarlo).

Comment: Además: probablemente quieras ejecutar `oCommand.ExecuteScalar()` (que devuelve el primer campo de la primera fila del resultado) en lugar de `oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` (que devuelve un entero con el total de filas afectadas por tu consulta)

Comment: Muchas gracias Roimer me has dado un par de ideas muy buenas, no había contado con ExecuteScalar() que es justo lo que necesitaba para esta consulta!! :)

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta, pero no es bueno para el sitio contestar preguntas que no cumplen con los requisitos mínimos de calidad del sitio. Te recomiendo la próxima vez tratar de guiar al OP para resolver los problema de su pregunta antes de responder. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

En el codigo a lo que veo estas intentando usar oConection antes de inicializarlo, en teoria tu problema se podria resolver cambiando esto:

```
    oConection.Open()
    oConection = New OleDbConnection(sConection)
```

por esto:

```
    oConection = New OleDbConnection(sConection)//primero creas el objeto
    oConection.Open()//despues lo utilizas
```

Explicacion: `oConection` es igual a `null` al ser `null` o no estar inicializado, no puedes acceder a sus metodos o atributos, por lo tanto antes de llamar `.open()` necesitas asignarle un valor al usar `=new` creas una nueva instancia de este objecto y asi es como evitas el error de *Objeto no inicializado*.

Alo que veo te faltat inicializar oConection, pero tendrias que validarlo, revisa la imagen para ver si te puede ayudar en algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cristina, no habria que haber esperado a que ponga su codigo como codigo, y no como imagen?? ;)

Comment: Si tambien... sorry

Comment: Por favor, edita la respuesta para poner lo que está en la imagen como texto en lugar de como una imagen. Las imágenes se ven peor (especialmente en dispositivos móviles donde son ilegibles) y no se indexa su contenido, por lo que todo el texto en rojo (que es donde está el verdadero cuerpo de la respuesta) no es fácil de encontrar. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Listo @AlvaroMontoro gracias por la observacion

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class GestionSql
Private sReturn As String = ""
Private sConection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\TPV.mdb;"
Private oConection As New OleDbConnection(sConection)
Public oCommand As New OleDbCommand
'Protected daAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sCmd, oConection)
'Protected dsDataSet As New DataSet

'Lanzar comandos con respuesta (SELECT)
Public Function Launch(ByVal value As String) As String
    Try
        oConection.Open()
        oCommand.CommandText = value
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        oCommand.Connection = oConection
        sReturn = oCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        oConection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("La contraseña es: " + sReturn.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Return sReturn
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Si esta respuesta es la solucion a tu problema, deberia ser la respuesta aceptada. No es necesario agregar como te quedo, ya que hace ruido en el sitio al no saber cual es la respuesta valida y aceptada.

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución cuando la encontraste, sería ideal que añadieras una pequeña descripción de qué cambiaste y por qué solucionó tu problema. Saludos.